# Character Encoding Issue with .NET Core API hosted on IIS when Using cURL from Ubuntu

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I have a .NET Core API that accepts a text parameter from the query string. The API works fine when hosted on Kestrel, but when I deploy it to IIS and make a request from Ubuntu using cURL, the text parameter value becomes garbled and shows as "ØªØ³Øª" instead of the expected "تست" (which means "test" in Persian).

I suspect that this issue is related to character encoding. The API should be able to interpret the UTF-8 encoded characters sent in the URL correctly, but it seems to have trouble doing so specifically when running on IIS and requested from Linux curl.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set your website via [.NET Globalization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh831368(v=ws.11)).

[image]